# Regarding the burden on Snowflake's database storage layer

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake has an architecture consisting of the following three layers.
・Database storage
・Query processing
・Cloud service

I understand that it is possible to create a warehouse for each process in query processing, and scale up and scale out on a per process basis.

However, when the created warehouses (processes) are processed in parallel, I am worried about the burden on the database storage.

Even though the query processing process can be load-balanced, since there is only one database storage, wouldn't there be a lot of parallel processing running in the database storage and an error occurring in the database storage layer?

Sorry if I don't understand the architecture.

Comment: "...wouldn't there be a lot of parallel processing running in the database storage..." Yes, but cloud object storage like S3, Azure Blob, and GCP Storage is designed to handle that. It's not like I/O in a disk, a set of disks, or even a SAN device. This storage is an entire distributed architecture spanning multiple availability zones.

Answer (score 1):

The storage is immutable, thus the query read load is just IO against cloud provider IO layers, so for all purposes infinitely scalable.

When any node updates a table, the new set of file partitions are known, and any warehouse without the new set of partition parts, does remote IO to read them.

The only downsides to this pattern is it does not scale well for transactional write patterns, thus why that is not the targeted at those markets.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Is it an image that a slave DB server is created for each process and query processing is performed there?

Comment: I believe this translated poorly. I was just comparing it to a multiple node postgres cluster, where one is the write node, and the others are read nodes. thus you get concurrent read performance.